# Internet Problem. NetworkManager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, 23.04, dhcpd

I was just using ifconfig and dhcpcd then my wifi connection just dissapeared. Went into settings and it just said: NetworkManager not running. I tried multiple different commands and it would not work. The only thing i did is do ifconfig, then do dhcpcd then my wlan. Nothing else.

ifconfig
*my connections*

dhcpcd wlan(then number)

Comment: does this problem persist following a reboot?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Yes. I tried rebooting several times but it still wouldnt run NetworkManage

Comment: I voted to leave this question open because I would also like to learn how to solve this problem.